# Powershell in C# not giving back all output

Tags: c#, powershell

I have a simple powershell instance and the results are printed to a textbox:

```
var results = PowerShellInstance.Invoke();
foreach (var item in results)
{
   ConsoleText += item + "\n";
}
```

But when I compare output to the regular powershell I don't get all the messages. For example using

> git checkout branch

the regular powershell gives back:

> Switched to branch 'branch'

Which is missing in the c# equivalent. I also tried the error, information and progress stream, but there are no messages.

Comment: Standard output (how a non-PowerShell cmdlet/function will show output) is not the same as the pipeline output that `Invoke` will return.

Comment: [This post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c/) includes some information (search for "standard") that may help.

Comment: "Besides the standard output stream, there are also dedicated streams for warnings, errors, debug, progress, and verbose logging"  

My code example is the standard output, isn't it? I also checked all the other streams but there are no more messages.

Comment: The referenced article conflates standard output (eg. from `Write-Host`) with the pipeline (eg. from `Write-Output`) so isn't as clear as it should be. Standard output doesn't appear to be in `PowerShell.Steams` (I've only integrated by using `Runspace` and related types so unsure here).

Comment: If all you want to do is invoke non-PowerShell code (like `git.exe`) why not execute directly with [`Process`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx) which allows you to capture standard output and error?